# images Intent does not open randomly. If I press the images in order intents are working

Tags: java, android

I have six images. If I press the first image intent is working. But if I press the third image firstly it is not working. it is working in order.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.indoor_activities);
    imageView.bringToFront();
    imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent (MainActivity.this,indoorActivities.class);
    startActivity(myIntent);

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.outdoor_activities);
    imageView.bringToFront();
    imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, outdoorActivities.class);
    startActivity(myIntent);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting other view click listener inside `R.id.indoor_activities`

In above code, you are saying that assign click listener every time to `outdoor_activities` if user click on `indoor_activities` first.

To fix this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.indoor_activities);
    imageView.bringToFront();
    imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent (MainActivity.this,indoorActivities.class);
    startActivity(myIntent);
});// click listener for indoor activities
// click listener for outdoor activities when onCreated is called
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.outdoor_activities);
    imageView.bringToFront();
    imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, outdoorActivities.class);
    startActivity(myIntent);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you should do like this.This will certainly works as your requirement.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.indoor_activities);
    imageView1.bringToFront();

    imageView1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent myIntent1 = new Intent (MainActivity.this,indoorActivities.class);
    startActivity(myIntent1);
       }
    });

    ImageView imageView2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.outdoor_activities);
    imageView2.bringToFront();
    imageView2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent myIntent2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, outdoorActivities.class);
    startActivity(myIntent2);      }
    });
```

Hope this helps you.